# divided into sections alphabetic my Tableview

Tags: ios, tableview, alphabetical, sections, divide

i have an array that contains name in string format (es.luca,marco,giuseppe,..).
This array will be used to fill the table.
how can I divide the table into sections (az) and put in the name of the array inside the right section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate through the array to create a dictionary with the first letter as the key and an array of names as a value:

**In Swift**

```
var nameDictionary: Dictionary<String, Array<String>> = [:]

for name in nameArray {
    var key = name[0].uppercaseString // first letter of the name is the key
    if let arrayForLetter = nameDictionary[key] { // if the key already exists
        arrayForLetter.append(name) // we update the value
        nameDictionary.updateValue(arrayForLetter, forKey: key) // and we pass it to the dictionary
    } else { // if the key doesn't already exists in our dictionary
        nameDictionary.updateValue([name], forKey: key) // we create an array with the name and add it to the dictionary
    }
}
```

**In Obj-C**

```
NSMutableDictionary *nameDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for name in nameArray {

    NSString *key =  [[name substringToIndex: 1] uppercaseString];

    if [nameDictionary objectForKey:key] != nil {

         NSMutableArray *tempArray = [nameDictionary objectForKey:key];
        [tempArray addObject: name];
        [nameDictionary setObject:tempArray forkey:key];
    } else {
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: name, nil];
        [nameDictionary setObject:tempArray forkey:key];
    }
}
```

then you can get your number of sections by using nameDictionary.count, the number of rows by getting nameDictionary[key].count and the content of your rows in a particular section with nameDictionary[key] which will return an array of all the names starting with the letter stored in key

**EDIT:** couple that with Piterwilson answer to have a full answer

**EDIT 2**: added Obj-C code

**Notice:** As I'm not on my mac, there might be small errors in the code but the principle remains the same

Comment: I use objective-c languages.

Comment: This is in swift, give me a few minutes and I'll edit my answer to include obj-C

Answer (score 2):

The question is a pretty straight forward implementation of UITableView with its delegate and datasource.

The actual explanation is a bit long, so here's a tutorial for an app that does something very similar to what you want.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/

Comment: That is the section that i need,but it doesn't explain how can divide the array in alfabetic order from A to Z.